# Encountering a type mismatch error using the application.Index function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a fairly simple code which is supposed to rename each worksheet in a workbook by indexing a table on the first worksheet. However, I am getting a type mismatch error on the rs.name line. I have tried switching between worksheetfunction.Index and application.Index but that makes no difference.

Here is the code:

```
Sub RenameSheet()

Dim rs As Worksheet

For Each rs In Sheets

rs.Name = Application.Index((Worksheets("Summary").Range("A6:B10")), Application.Match(rs.Range("B2"), Worksheets("Summary").Range("A6:A10"), 0), 1, 0)

Next rs

End Sub
```

Comment: It's best to test if `Appliction.Match` returns an error before attempting to use its return value.

Comment: Why the last argument `0`? What is your goal in using the *area_num* argument?

Comment: Could you share what's in `Summary!A6:B10` and in `rs.Range("B2")`?

Comment: `Application.Index(Worksheets("Summary").Range("A6:B10"), Application.Match(rs.Range("B2"), Worksheets("Summary").Range("A6:A10"), 0), 2)`  Using `Application.VLookup(rs.Range("B2"), Worksheets("Summary").Range("A6:B10"), 2, False)` would be simpler though. You only need Index/Match when the lookup column is to the right of the data you want to return.